# Trying to install hommie pcie wifi bt card [8086:0014] on kernel 5.11.0-27-generic

Tags: wireless, pcie

I need help installing a wireless-ac2100 pcie adapter on ubuntu kernel 5.11.0-27-generic.

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)

```
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:0014]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no

```
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: [   10.465007] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   10.465009] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   10.466030] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   11.486008] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz, REV=0x324
[   11.534291] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Can't parse empty family 8000 OTP/NVM sections
[   11.534306] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to read NVM: -61
[   11.546172] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -61